# Why does this simple AJAX example from MDN fail?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm attempting to run JavaScript similar to the example given under "Step 3 – A Simple Example" of the MDN [AJAX Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started).  For reference, here is the code for that example:

```
<button id="ajaxButton" type="button">Make a request</button>

<script>
(function() {
  var httpRequest;
  document.getElementById("ajaxButton").addEventListener('click', makeRequest);

  function makeRequest() {
    httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

    if (!httpRequest) {
      alert('Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
      return false;
    }
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = alertContents;
    httpRequest.open('GET', 'test.html');
    httpRequest.send();
  }

  function alertContents() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
        alert(httpRequest.responseText);
      } else {
        alert('There was a problem with the request.');
      }
    }
  }
})();
</script>
```

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var httpRequest;
        window.addEventListener('click', getData, false, { once: true });

        function getData(){
            httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

            if (!httpRequest) {
                alert('Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
                return false;
            }
            httpRequest.onreadystatechange = handleData;
            httpRequest.open("POST", "ajax_test.php", true);
            httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            httpRequest.send();
        }

        function handleData() {
            console.log("Handling data");
        }
    })();
</script>
```

There's a few differences, but the basic structure is nearly identical.

The content of `ajax_test.php` is `<?php echo "DATA"; ?>`.

When I run my code in a browser, the `handleData()` function fires twice when I click anywhere in the window, and I get "Handling data" twice in the console.  More bizarrely, if I add a trivial loop to the function:

```
function handleData() {
    for (var i=0; i<1; i++) {
        console.log(i);
    }
    console.log("Handling data");
}
```

it fires *four* times, and I get

```
0
Handling data
0
Handling data
0
Handling data
0
Handling data
```

in the console when I click anywhere once.

It doesn't matter if I change the AJAX method to GET.  It also doesn't matter if I change the `window` eventListener to 'load' instead of 'click'.  It doesn't matter if I use the full URL for `ajax_test.php`.  It's the same behavior in all cases.  This happens in both Chromium 81 and Firefox 76.

What's the source of the error?

Comment: You're missing `if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE)`. The state changed 4 times, but you only want DONE, the others are not interesting

Comment: @JeremyThille That makes so much sense now that I see it.  I had removed that line because I'd been getting "`httpRequest` is undefined" errors, but it looks like I've fixed that problem.  I think this is the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `handleData` whenever the `readystatechange` event fires.

Unlike the example from MDN, you don't test to see what the state has changed to. You do all the work in the function even if the state isn't yet `DONE`

You might want to use the `load` event instead.